# Why can Quaternion.FromToRotation(rotation * axis, axis) * rotation limit one DOF?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, quaternions

I came across this line code from the Unity plugin Final IK.

The whole funtion is like this:

```
//Limits rotation to a single degree of freedom (along axis)

protected static Quaternion Limit1DOF(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 axis) 
{
  return Quaternion.FromToRotation(rotation * axis, axis) * rotation;
}
```

This seems elegant and fast, but I cannot understand how this can work. Why can this limit one DOF?

Comment: More elegant to use "swing twist decomposition" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, the `FromToRotation()` part is reverting any rotation component about an axis other than `axis`. It is doing this by pushing the rotated axis back to `axis`.

In some more detail: You want to find a rotation `R1DOF` that is close to `R` and that is restricted to a single degree of freedom (rotation about `axis`). Hence, you want that transforming `axis` with `R` preserves `axis`:

```
R1DOF * axis = axis
```

I am slightly abusing notation here since `R` is a quaternion and transformation by a quaternion is not simply a single multiplication. Let's instead state that `*` is the transformation operator.

Now, we are representing `R1DOF` as `M * R`, where `M` is a modification rotation that maps `R * axis` to `axis`. Let's call `axisAfterR = R * axis` for clarity. If we do this, then:

```
R1DOF * axis = M * R * axis
             = M * axisAfterR
```

Since we defined `M` such that it maps `axisAfterR` to `axis`, we have

```
             = axis
```

which is just what we wanted.

Hence, `axis` (and thereby all its multiples) are fixpoints of `R1DOF`. Therefore, `R1DOF` is a rotation about `axis`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot understand what `R1DOF * axis = axis `mean, and despite the prove, how can I get the answer `Quaternion.FromToRotation(rotation * axis, axis) * rotation`?

Comment: `R1DOF * axis = axis` means that if you transform `axis` with `R1DOF`, you will get `axis`. What answer does the second part of your question refer to? `Quaternion.FromToRotation(rotation * axis, axis)` is what I called `M` in my answer.

Comment: `R1DOF * axis = axis means that if you transform axis with R1DOF, you will get axis`... Isn't `R1DOF` a rotation that is verticle to the `axis`? How can I get `axis` by transforming `axis` with `R1DOF` please?

Comment: Oh I knew it! Limiting one dof can be regarded as fixing the axis after applying the rotation! So that make sense.